# Is there an idiom for a loop that executes some block of instructions between iterations? (In Ruby in particular)

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

I often need to do some operations in a loop and some other operations between the iterations.  A simple example would be collecting words from an array into a string, spelled backwards and separated with commas. Is there an idiom or language support for this in any language? (For now i am mostly interested in Ruby.)

I usually do something like

```rb
a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
s = ''
n = a.size - 1
i = 0
loop do
  s << a[i].reverse
  break if i == n
  s << ', '
  i += 1
end
```

But i know no good way to save this half iteration if using a ruby iterator.

This looks redundant:

```rb
a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
s = ''
a.each do |w|
  s << w.reverse
  s << ', ' unless w == a.last
end
```

---

**Update 1.** A more practical example is creating a Haml template where blocks of HTML are created in a loop and need to be concatenated with other blocks of HTML.

---

**Update 2.** On [programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188501/) it was suggested that my problem is called the "loop-and-a-half" problem.

---

**Update 3.** I failed to be able to apply the Map-Reduce pattern in Haml because Haml does not allow to close a block with `end` (it just uses indentation), so i've found no way to chain `map` and `reduce`. So in some sense this question is still open, but maybe it is also closed because there is no way to do this. So this is a clopen question, i guess.

Comment: "In between iterations?" This does not make sense to me. Could you clarify?

Comment: I wanted to ask it on Programmers first, but the site was refusing the question for some reason, so i asked here, but then managed to ask on Programmers too. Sorry for double posting.

Comment: google for "ruby functional programming"

Comment: @tokland, and what then?

Comment: read the articles/posts? your code shows that you have only experience with imperative programming, that's a serious problem if you are going to write idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: I still would like you to be more specific, your answer is not answering my question.

Comment: Sawa's answer is the more idiomatic . It makes use of the basic functional abstractions (`map`). Functional programming in a nutshell: don't update variables, use higher-order functions, use expressions not statements.

Comment: @takland, i know about functional programming in general, i was interested in concrete solutions to this "loop-and-a-half" problem. Don named the appropriate pattern, but i want to wait just in case if there are other solutions more appropriate inside a Haml template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a distinction between the processing of each element in an array and other processing that transforms the resulting array in some manner.  These are "map" and "reduce" in the MapReduce model.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapreduce

Comment: Don, I am almost ready to accept your answer, but i want to see if there will be other suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not see how to use MapReduce in a Haml template without obscuring the template.

Answer (score 4):

A standard Ruby way is:

```
a.map(&:reverse).join(", ")
```

Comment: I know this, i am interested in a general solution. I gave an example just for example.

Comment: Say, there is a block of code that needs to be iterated over, and another block of code that needs to be run between the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] 
a.each do |w|
    w.reverse!
end
s = a.join(',')
```

Is this what you were looking for? Output is:

`oof,rab,zab`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform such an operation often, you may easily extend `Array` with:

```
class Array
  def join_cb
    inject ('') { |v, e| 
      v += "#{e}#{yield e unless e == self.last}"
    }
  end
end
```

And use it like:

```
> a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
> a.map(&:reverse).join_cb { '%' }
# ⇒ "oof%rab%zab"
```

Or, to make a concat string dependent on array element:

```
> a.map(&:reverse).join_cb { |e| e == 'rab' ? '-' : '_' }
# ⇒ "oof_rab-zab"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution that works even in Haml, it was suggested to me to do as follows:

```rb
a.each_with_index do |item, index|
  unless index.zero?
    # do what is to be done between the iterations
  end
  # do what is to be done on all iterations
end
```

I am using it now, but of course it is not optimal: the conditional is run on every iteration. As a minor inconvenience, the previous item is not accessible "between iterations."